# Clustering a sparse dataset of binary vectors

Tags: cluster-analysis, distance, sparse-matrix

If I have a sparse dataset where each data is described by a vector of 1000 elements, each element of this vector can be either 0 or 1 (a lot of 0 and some 1), do you know any distance function that could help me to cluster them ? Is something like euclidean distance convenient in this case ? I would like to know if there is a simple convenient distance metric for such a situation, to try on my data.

Thanks

Comment: How about the distortion function used in K-meloids? It is not very different from Euclidean distance.

Comment: @CRK K-meloids uses [Minkowski distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) with p = 1, which is a general case of euclidean distance, isn't it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at distance functions used for sparse text vectors, such as Cosine Distance and for comparing sets, such as the Jaccard distance.

Answer (score 13):

Your question doesn't have one answer. There are best-practices depending on the domain.

Once you decide on the similarity metric, the clustering is usually done by averaging or by finding a medoid. See these papers on clustering binary data for algorithm examples:

> - Carlos Ordonez. Clustering Binary Data Streams with K-means. [PDF](http://www.bradblock.com/Clustering_Binary_Data_Streams_with_K_means.pdf)
> - Tao Li. A General Model for Clustering Binary Data. [PDF](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~taoli/tenure/p188-li.pdf)

For ideas on similarity measures see this online ["tool for measuring similarity between binary strings"](http://www.miislita.com/searchito/binary-similarity-calculator.html). They mention:  Sokal-Michener, Jaccard, Russell-Rao, Hamann, Sorensen, antiDice, Sneath-Sokal, Rodger-Tanimoto, Ochiai, Yule, Anderberg, Kulczynski, Pearson's Phi, and Gower2,  Dot Product, Cosine Coefficient, Hamming Distance.
They also cite these papers:

> - Luke, B. T., Clustering Binary Objects
> - Lin, D., An Information-Theoretic Definition of Similarity.
> - Toit, du S.H.C.; Steyn, A.G.W.; Stumpf, R.H.; Graphical Exploratory Data Analysis; Chapter 3, p. 77, 1986; Springer-Verlag.

(I personally like the cosine. There is also KL-divergence, and its Jensen distance counterpart.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is an interesting link. But, say we use the Hamming (or cosine or any other distance), how can we learn the representative of each group of vectors. I mean, let's say we have v1= 0100100001100 and v2 = 0001100001100, they are close to each other since they differ only in two bits (the 2nd and 3rd positions) then Hamming distance for example will be 2 (cosine will be 0.7500), the problem is: what will be the representative vector of v1 and v2 ? How to (learn) just the values of the vector that should represent v1 and v2 and all other vectors that are close to them.

Comment: The representative vector is an average (*centroid*, not binary) or a *medoid*. Read the papers for examples on finding those.

Comment: Dead Link "tool for measuring similarity between binary strings"

Answer (score 3):

Many distance / similarity function for binary vectors have been proposed.

In [A Survey of Binary Similarity and Distance Measures - Choi, Cha, Tappert 2010](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.352.6123), the authors list 76 such functions.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is lots of 0 and a few 1, you could try clustering for the first or last 1 - see http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Least Significant 1 Bit

Comment: First or last one ? How is the function metric between the two vectors defined in this case ? Distance(V1, V2)